# Javadoc @link tag not working in module-info.java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javadoc, java-platform-module-system

I've added Javadoc comments to my `module-info` file in my project and in a paragraph, placed a `{@link}` tag that references one of the packages in my project.  I've also added a `package-info.java` in the referenced source package which also contains a javadoc comment, and it builds and renders fine.  When I run javadoc on the project, I receive the error below.  I would like a clickable link to be rendered in the generated javadoc but only monospaced text appears in the intended link text.

```
[ERROR] X:\my-project\src\main\java\module-info.java:6: error: reference not found
[ERROR]  *   <p>The {@link myproject.tools} package contains the utility classes</p>
[ERROR]                    ^
```

My `module-info.java` located at the root of the source tree, `src/java/main/` is:

```
/**
 * My module documentation.
 *   <p>The {@link myproject.tools} package contains the utility classes</p>
 */
module MyProject {
...
}
```

My `package-info.java` is located:

```
<project-root>
  +---- src/main/java/module-info.java
  +---- src/main/java/myproject/tools/package-info.java
  +---- src/main/java/myproject/tools/<various_classes_here>
```

and contains:

```
/**
 * This package contains my tools classes.
 */
package myproject.tools;
```

I'm using Maven 3, JDK 11, and Eclipse 4.13.  It properly generates all other javadoc API documentation but errors on this link tag.  It hasn't worked with this link tag at all since I added it.

Here is my maven-javadoc-plugin section:

```xml
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludePackageNames>org.*</excludePackageNames>
            <show>package</show>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
            <reportSet>
                <id>default</id>
                <reports>
                    <report>javadoc</report>
                </reports>
            </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
    </plugin>
...
</reporting>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludePackageNames>org.*</excludePackageNames>
            <show>package</show>
            <reportOutputDirectory>docs/javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
</build>
```

Here is the command line as reported by Javadoc in the error output:

```
[ERROR] Command line was: cmd.exe /X /C "C:\JDK1110\bin\javadoc.exe @options @argfile"
```

Running both `mvn site` and `mvn javadoc:javadoc` produce this error. What am I doing wrong here?

**Expected**

According to the [Javadoc standard doclet specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html) which states:

> *{@link package.class#member label }*

> Inserts an inline link with a visible text label that points to the documentation for the specified **package**, class, or member name of a referenced class. This tag is valid in all documentation comments: overview, **module**, package, class, interface, constructor, method and field, including the text portion of any tag, such as the @return, @param and @deprecated tags.

(bold text emphasis is mine)

I was using the JRE's `jdk.jshell.module-info.class` as an example of the desired behavior which contains `{@link package-name}` and renders a clickable link in the corresponding module documentation [as seen here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk.jshell-summary.html).  Note that `@moduleGraph` is not supported by the standard doclet.

**What I Tried**

Everything compiles fine except when I add this `{@link}` as described in this question.

Changing the `{@link}` to `{@code}` renders onto the page as expected but of course no link and no error.

*However*, in Eclipse, I can hover over the module declaration line and it renders the javadoc described above ***with** a link* to my package (as shown in the paragraph above in a popup window) and after clicking, *correctly* navigates me to my package-info javadoc and renders that as well.

I've also added the following statement to my `module-info` but does not solve the problem:

```java
    opens myproject.tools to java.base, jdk.javadoc, javadoc;
```

Works in Eclipse (hover-over idenifier for javadoc) but not when using the Javadoc CLI (through Maven).

Comment: Are you able to link something not project-related, e.g. `java.lang.String` (with the appropriate link-mapping for the JDK links)? How about class and member references? Lastly, you are using absolute references, correct?

Comment: is this your location: `src/java/main/`? That should be `src/main/java`??

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks! fixed typo (console output is correct)

Comment: Does your module `exports myproject.tools`? If not, it's possible the `javadoc` tool fails on that link because it points to non-public API, which is not being documented, whereas the module is part of the public API, which _is_ being documented. Does executing `javadoc` with `--show-packages all` get rid of the error?

Comment: @Rogue yes, I added this text to `module-info.java`: `{@link java.lang.String} is a helpful class, {@link java.util} contains
the Collections Framework.`  Both links work fine.  Absolute refs, I think `myproject.tools` is an absolute ref to the package, AKA fully qualified.  I was able to link to both a class and a method in my project, in `myproject.tools` specifically from `module-info`.

Comment: I would guess that being in the top-level directory might have something to do with it, but I'm not certain myself. Try a `module-info` located in one of your packages. It's not impossible this is a bug or something that's documented as unsupported.

Comment: @Slaw not sure I need to if I can link to a class and a method in that package?  They build and render into the page fine.  Adding the suggested `exports` didn't work.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem (using Gradle) on Java 19. Linking to a package in the module's JavaDoc works fine for me.

Comment: @Slaw very interesting.  Perhaps it's an issue that was resolved since JDK 11.  Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following statement to `module-info.java` took care of the error:

```
   exports myproject.tools;
```

However, this seems to defeat the purpose of JPMS modules since this makes the package available to outside libraries/applications (unintended), simply for the purpose of a "link-to-self".  Based on comments from @slaw, I suspect this issue turned out to be a bug that was resolved in a future version of Javadoc and works properly in JDK 19.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Perhaps I could change it to `exports myproject.tools to javadoc, jdk.javadoc, javax.tools;` to minimize the exposure.  Alas, this doesn't work.  Just need the correct target package for the Javadoc tool.

Comment: Without `exports` it's internal. Mentioning internals in the public API is against the concept of modularization/encapsulation. [`java.base`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/module-summary.html) does not mention nor list any of its `sun.*` packages neither.

Comment: Agree with howlger. If `myproject.tools` is an internal package, then mentioning it (let alone linking to it) in public documentation is antithetical to the purpose of distinguishing between public and internal APIs.

Comment: New to JPMS, but I think I see your points. So `module-info` is for public documentation only?

Comment: `module-info` is public which makes its Javadoc public too.

Comment: @Slaw when you attempted this with JDK 19, did you have an `export` statement for the package to support the link or no export? I see now that `jdk.jshell` has a matching `export` for each of its links in the module-info javadoc comment.

Comment: If you're struggling to understand modularity in Java (JPMS), this was hugely informative: https://youtu.be/rfOjch4p0Po

Comment: It worked for me regardless of the package being exported. Note I generated the JavaDoc via Gradle, which could possibly do something slightly different than Maven.